# gfxinfo for Android webview

Tags: android, performance, android-webview, frame-rate

I am testing my Android application which has Android webview, to check UI performance i am using `adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo <packagename>` to get the fps value and janky frames.

I can see visually that UI performance is quite good(there is no lags) but the fps numbers are coming as 20 for 95th percentile and janky frames percentage is 98%

Upon profiling from chrome devtools i can see fps as 60

adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo works well for native apps but not for webview.

Is there any other way to check this ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

For measuring your webpage performance inside the webview you can use chrome DevTools. First go to chrome://inspect/devices. There you should be able to see your connected device and a list of all your active webviews. Make sure you have adb setup and your device is authorized.

Next press **Command+Shift+P** or **Ctrl+Shift+P** to bring up the run command menu and type FPS, and select

> Show Frames Per Second (FPS) meter

This will bring up a live FPS meter. It looks something like this

[image]